# Stoping spring Jpa + hibernate from rewriting values in joined database

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am starting to learn Hibernate and spring JPA and trying to connect two tables but can't make it work properly.
Here are my classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
            @JoinColumn(name="username", referencedColumnName="username")
    List<UserRole> userRoles;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String grp;
    @Id
    private String username;

    public User() {
        userRoles=new ArrayList<>();
        userRoles.add(new UserRole("default"));
    }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class UserRole  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "role_name")
    String roleName;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  roleName;
    }

    public UserRole(String role) {
        roleName = role;
    }
```

The problem I have is when I'm using JpaRepository's save method to update user the role values are repeated in roles table.
For example if I'm having a user with ADMIN ROLE and using save to firstly add the user to table and then to update his email I'm getting two identical role fields with different IDs.(if I'm putting nullable tag false)
Otherwise, it just gets me a new field with null as a username, ADMIN role and new ID.
I understand that it might be connected to generationType.IDENTITY. But if I'm making it AUTO I get the Table 'project2testing.hibernate_sequence' exception.
Could you help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you likely want is an Xref table and `ManyToMany`, which I don't see here. What you're saying now is that there is a single relationship between a user and many roles. In other words, roles are not re-usable. They belong to a user, and every time you assign a user to a role, even if a role with that name already exists, a new role will be created.

Instead, `ManyToMany` makes more sense. A role is not traditionally a unique thing to a user, and many users may have the same role.

One way to achieve that is this:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = UserRole.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="user_role_xref", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
Set<UserRole> userRoles;
```

This will create a `user_role_xref` table that will contain two columns: `username` and `role_id` that reference `User.username` and `UserRole.id` respectively. Note that this will require managing `UserRole` independently of users, which seems more desirable in this scenario. Just because a role isn't currently assigned to a user doesn't mean it should be deleted.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Wish you all the best.